# Parallelizing loop for downloading data

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I want to run a simple script in Google App Engine that retrieves many files into an object as quickly as possible. Would parallelization be a smart option and how would I go about doing it? Thanks in advance for the brainstorming

```
import requests

...
theData=[]
for q in range(0, len(theURLs)):

    r = requests.get(theURLs[q])
    theData.insert(q,r.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "regular" Python this is pretty simple.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import requests
responses = ThreadPool(10).map(requests.get, urls)
```

Replace 10 with # of threads that produces best results for you.

However you specified GAE which has restrictions on spawning threads/processes and its own async approach, which consists of using the async functions from the [URL Fetch service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request), something along these lines (untested):

```
rpcs = [urlfetch.create_rpc() for url in urls]
for (rpc, url) in zip(rpcs, urls):
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
results = [rpc.get_result() for rpc in rpcs]
```

You will need to add error handling...

Answer (score 3):

You should make your code more Pythonic by using list comprehensions:

```
# A list of tuples
theData = [(q,requests.get(theURLs[q]).text) for q in range(0, len(theURLs))]

# ... or ...

# A list of lists
theData = [[q,requests.get(theURLs[q]).text] for q in range(0, len(theURLs))]
```

If you want to retrieve the files concurrently use the `threading` library, this website has some good examples, might be good practice:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: The whole thing in just one line, that's elegance! Could it be without the q as first argument, like this: `theData = [q,requests.get(theURLs[q]).text for q in range(0, len(theURLs))]` ? Otherwise I get error

Comment: Oh oops sorry about that I missed either the closing brackets (for a tuple) or square brackets (for a list), see the edit, should work now. It depends what you want to do with the data really, tuples are immutable, lists are not.

Comment: I highly recommend this webpage to learn Python, and write Pythonic code very quickly, assuming you have previous knowledge on other languages (has a lot of good info on tuples vs lists, etc): http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html

Comment: It's also more Pythonic to avoid list indexes wherever they are not necessary, e.g. `[(url, requests.get(url).text) for url in urls]`

Comment: @JasonS yes that's a good point, however I think he wants to use the integer index as the first pair of the tuple or list, which is why I kept the range based for loop.

Answer (score -1):

I seriously doubt it.  Parallelization can really only speed up calculations, while the bottleneck here is data transfer.